# element not triggered by attached eventhandler

Tags: jquery, html

i have a `<div id="pause"><img id="pausimg" src="bla" /></div>` as a button which fires me the following event:

```
$('#pause').on('click', pause);
$('#play').on('click', play);

function pause() {
    $slider.cycle('resume'); 
    $('#pausimg').attr('src', 'images/pause.png'); 
    $(this).attr('id', 'play');
}

function play() { $slider.cycle('pause');
     $('#pausimg').attr('src', 'images/play.png');
     $(this).attr('id', 'pause');
}
```

as you can see `#play`does not exist at the point when clicking the button. but after clicking it, the handler `play()` should fire. but it seems that it doesnt know `#play`even if i check with logs that the `id`is actually  `#play`

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RFg7C/1/)**

Use event delegation:

```
$('body').on('click', '#pause', pause);
$('body').on('click', '#play', play);
```

---

References:

- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - jQuery API Documentation

Comment: works pretty good! but honestly i dont get what is happening there! shouldnt this work with my code too?

Comment: @supersize When you want to attach event handlers to element which doesn't exists yet, you should use **event delegation**.

Answer (score 0):

Use a container for event delegation:

**HTML**

```
<div id="controlsContainer">
   <div id="pause"><img id="pausimg" src="bla" /></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#controlsContainer').on('click', '#pause', pause);
$('#controlsContainer').on('click', '#play', play);
```